# getResources array xml in pageradapter

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I try to pass value from `xml array` to `Listfragment`.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    static Context context;
    static Resources res = null;
    static String[] CONTENT = null;


    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
        super(fm);

        context = c;


    }


    @Override
    public ListFragment getItem(int index) {


        res = context.getResources();
        CONTENT = res.getStringArray(R.array.trg_values);

          ListFragment fragment = new DaerahFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("daerah", CONTENT[index] ); 
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 7;
    }
}
```

***here is my xml***

```
    <string-array name="trg_values">
    <item name="Kuala Terengganu">1</item>
    <item name="Marang">2</item>
    <item name="Dungun">3</item>
    <item name="Kemaman">4</item>
    <item name="Hulu Terengganu">5</item>
    <item name="Setiu">6</item>
    <item name="Besut">7</item>

</string-array>
```

**Error:**

```
08-03 16:12:00.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
08-03 16:12:00.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.jkmt.ppbanjir.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter.getItem(TabsPagerAdapter.java:62)
```

***Adapter's instantiation***

```
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null); 
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: how are you instatiating the adapter ? Remove `static` from the members of your adapter

Comment: nothing happen.same error

Comment: how are you instatiating the adapter ?

Comment: do you mean initilization?

Comment: mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: and how do you expect to work if you pass `null` as Context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

you are passing null as `Context`, and assigning null to the member in your Adapter. When getItem is called, and the member referenced, the app crashes for `NullPointerException`. Change it with

```
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
```

if you are inside an `Activity`, or

```
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());
```

if you are inside a `Fragment`